# Client-server application in Java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, client, server

I have a server application in Java, that holds a list of Student objects (implementing Serializable). The client application sends a message with an integer - index of Student object to fetch. Then the selected Student is sent to the client, the client modifies its value and sends back. The application however freezes at some point, and it's probably a problem with the lines I emphasized in the code below.

Server:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        ArrayList <Student> studentList = new ArrayList <Student> ();
        studentList.add(new Student(170435, "justyna", "kaluzka", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170438, "michal", "szydlowski", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170436, "marek", "polewczyk", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170439, "jakub", "szydlowski", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170430, "anna", "majchrzak", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170425, "krzysztof", "krawczyk", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170445, "adam", "szydlowski", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170415, "karol", "chodkiewicz", new ArrayList <Float>()));
        studentList.add(new Student(170465, "artur", "schopenhauer", new ArrayList <Float>()));

        ServerSocket socketConnection = null;
        ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = null;
        ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = null;

        try {
            socketConnection = new ServerSocket(11111);
            System.out.println("Server Waiting");

            Socket pipe = socketConnection.accept();

            serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream( pipe.getOutputStream());
            serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream( pipe.getInputStream());

            int index = serverInputStream.readInt();
            System.out.println(index);

            //  HERE'S WHEN THE PROBLEM STARTS
            serverOutputStream.writeObject(studentList.get(index));
            Student student = (Student) serverInputStream.readObject();

            System.out.println(student.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                serverInputStream.close();
                serverOutputStream.close();
                socketConnection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Student student = null;
        Socket socketConnection = null;
        ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = null;
        ObjectInputStream clientInputStream = null;

        try {
            socketConnection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 11111);

            clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socketConnection.getOutputStream());
            clientInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socketConnection.getInputStream());

            clientOutputStream.writeInt(0);
            student = (Student) clientInputStream.readObject();

            student.setFamilyName("Konopnicka");

            clientOutputStream.writeObject(student);    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                clientOutputStream.close();
                clientInputStream.close();
                socketConnection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My knowledge of client-server sockets is vague, so it's most likely a simple mistake. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Student class

```
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5169551431906499332L;
    private int indexNumber;
    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private ArrayList<Float> marks;
    private float average;

    public Student(int indexNumber, String name, String familyName,
            ArrayList<Float> marks) {
        this.indexNumber = indexNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.familyName = familyName;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.average = 0;
        generateMarks();
        calculateAverage();
    }

    public int getIndexNumber() {
        return indexNumber;
    }

    public void setIndexNumber(int indexNumber) {
        this.indexNumber = indexNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return familyName;
    }

    public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
        this.familyName = familyName;
    }

    public float getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    public void setAverage(float average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates average of all Student's marks.
     */
    public void calculateAverage() {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++) {
            sum += marks.get(i);
        }
        this.average = sum / marks.size();
    }

    /**
     * Generates a random set of marks for the student.
     */
    public void generateMarks() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addMark(new Random().nextFloat() * 5);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Mark getter
     * 
     * @return String representation of marks
     */
    public String getMarks() {
        String marksstr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++) {
            marksstr += marks.get(i).toString() + "   ";
        }
        return marksstr;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a mark to the list.
     * 
     * @param mark
     */
    public void addMark(float mark) {
        marks.add(mark);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Index number:" + indexNumber + "\tName:" + name
                + "\tFamily name:" + familyName + "\t\tAverage:" + getAverage()
                + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your objects are serializable?

Comment: After `"Here's where the problem starts"` how far do you get?  To the `println` two lines below?

Comment: Nope, I only got "Server Waiting" on the server side, and on the client side nothing.

Comment: And ofc it's serializable.

Comment: It works fine until this line: student = (Student) clientInputStream.readObject(); That's when it starts to not respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize your `ObjectOutputStream` before your `ObjectInputSteam` on your server.

When you initialize an `ObjectInputStream`, it waits for "header" data. Your server is waiting for that header data. You need to initialize your `ObjectOutputStream` first (which sends the header data), THEN your `ObjectInputStream`.

You can find more about this in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825187/2398375)

---

You must flush your `ObjectOutputStream` after writing the int. When you write data to a stream, it gets written into a buffer. Data from that buffer is only sent when the stream's buffer is full. An int does not fill it, so you must `flush()` it to manually send the data from the buffer.

Comment: @markspace That's assuming you are not following a strict protocol. Also, even when reading/writing using different threads, some people like to keep the initialization centeralized for easy management. It's best to just do it the right way, understanding the cause of the problem. But you're right; initializing on different threads will also solve the problem

Comment: Okay, the trick is: I'd like to send an integer from client to server, then send an object from server to client, let the client modify it, and send it back to the server. Is it doable by simply creating two Runnables (one for reading, one for writing), and starting two threads?

Comment: @user4359659 Yes, but do you *NEED* 2 threads? I don't think so, and I wouldn't recommend it (try to avoid concurrency if possible so you dont have to worry about atomicy or synchronization). Just have the client `writeInt`, then `readObject`, then finally `writeObject` again. Do the opposite on your server. No extra threads needed

Comment: Yes, but that's how I do it right now. Just using one main thread. And it's not working ;)

Comment: @user4359659 You need to tell me exactly how it's not working. You have not updated your code to reflect that you've done what I have suggested. If you still get further problems, first update your code, then tell me the problem you are having. I'm a programmer, not a mind reader

Comment: Okay, wait. Maybe we just didn't get it straight. Do I use any additional thread or not?

Comment: @user4359659 No, you don't need to. You can do it all on one thread. Just initialize your outputstreams before your inputstreams so `ObjectInputStream` doesn't block when you initialize it

Comment: okay, I did it, updated the code. still the same effect, though, it just stops. if I remove the part with object sending, it all goes fine, if I remove the part with integer sending, also works fine. but not the two of them together

Comment: @user4359659 After investigating a little more, I found the problem. Read my edit

Comment: Of course you're right. Like I said, I'm inept in the subject. Simple mistake, quite obvious for anyone who's done it at least once. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: @user4359659 No worries :) If you want some advice, I suggest sending only the state over the network, rather than the entire object. I find the purpose of `Object*Stream`s to be for writing objects to a drive, or sending it to an object database. You could instead use `Data*Stream`s. Have the client send an "opcode" to let the server know what to do with the incoming data (`1` could be change family name). After sending the opcode, send the ID of the user you wanna change the name of, then the name right after that. If you want, I could give you an example

Comment: Oh yes, that does seem reasonable, the less we clutter the buffer, the better I guess, even more so if the object is bigger, right? I think I see how would it work, just define some dictionary of operations, send the opcode to the server, and then call the appropriate function. The reason I did it this way was mainly for the academic exercise, which was just put this way. But your point is absolutely valid, thanks for feedback ;)